# Controller, repo and twig print array (Symfony3)

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-3.3

I need to print domains of a single user

### ENTITY (here is the entity code)

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Domini
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="domini")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\DominiRepository")
 */
class Domini
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_user", type="integer")
     */
    private $idUser;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dominio", type="string", length=100, unique=true)
     */
    private $dominio;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set idUser
     *
     * @param integer $idUser
     *
     * @return Domini
     */
    public function setIdUser($idUser)
    {
        $this->idUser = $idUser;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idUser
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getIdUser()
    {
        return $this->idUser;
    }

    /**
     * Set dominio
     *
     * @param string $dominio
     *
     * @return Domini
     */
    public function setDominio($dominio)
    {
        $this->dominio = $dominio;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dominio
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDominio()
    {
        return $this->dominio;
    }
}
```

### REPOSITORY (here is the Repo code)

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;
use AppBundle\Entity\Domini;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class DominiRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @return dominio[]
     */
    public function findAllPublishedOrderedBySize()
    {

        $query = 'SELECT dominio FROM AppBundle:Domini dominio';
        $mydomain = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($query);
        return $mydomain->execute();

    }
}
```

### CONTROLLER

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Controller/DominiController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Domini;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class DominiController extends Controller
{
/**
     * @Route("/admin/domini")
     */
    public function dominiAction()
    {
        $title = "ADMIN";
        $nome_utente = $this->getUser();

            $user = $this->getUser()->getId();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $dominilist = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Domini')
        ->findAllPublishedOrderedBySize();

        return $this->render('admin/domini.html.twig', [
            'title' => $title,
            'nome_utente' => $nome_utente,
            'user' => $user,
            'dominilist' => $dominilist,
        ]);

    }

}
```

### TWIG

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<h2>Benvenuto: {{ nome_utente }}</h2>
<h3>USER ID:{{ user }}</h3>


<ul>
    {% for item in dominilist %}
        <li>{{ item.dominio }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

### MYSQL TABLE

table name: domini

fields: id, id_user, dominio

Now all works fine but  'dominilist' => $dominilist doesn't work. Dominio is the domain name saved under "dominio". Why?

IF i try to cicle this field it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try $mydomain->getResult()?

Comment: before execute, instead of execute? what...

Comment: instead of execute() method. Regards

Comment: yes.. nothing happens (no error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select all the data stored in that table, you can use a quick and handy method directly in your controller

```
# Controller
$dominilist = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Domini')
    ->findAll();
```

Or you can find `domini` by `id` in the controller too:

```
# Controller
$user = $this->getUser()->getId();
$dominilist = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Domini')->findBy(['id'=>$user]);
```

And only if you want to have a more complex query, then you can create q method in the repository. As that "I need to print domains of a single user"

```
# Repository
public function findAllPublishedOrderedBySize($id)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d');
    $qb
        ->select('d.dominio')
        ->where('d.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
    ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}

# Controller
$user = $this->getUser()->getId();
$domini = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Domini')
    ->findAllPublishedOrderedBySize($user);
```

Anyway, those type of queries are small, and you can create them in the controller, as I showed you above.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154177/discussion-on-answer-by-dan-costinel-controller-repo-and-twig-print-array-symf). Make sure that you [edit] the answer to include all relevant information.

Comment: ah, sorry, it's: `$dominilist = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Domini')->findB‌​‌​y(['id_user' => $user]);`

Comment: $id_user = $this->getUser()->getId();
--------------
$dominilist = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Domini')->findBy(['id_user' => $id_user]);
------------
Unrecognized field: id_user

Comment: edit your original post, at the very top of this page, and include the code of your `AppBundle/Entity/Domini.php` file

Comment: DAMN: .........findBy(['idUser' => $id_user]);

but... why symfony rewrite the name of the table? why i must to do it??? so crazy...

Comment: the default behaviour is that the name of the table will be the name of the entity.

Comment: the problem was in the name of the column... cause id_user is a column, not the name of the table... anyway! many thanks. i consider very helpful your advices!!